# Do I need root access for accessing internal classes?

Tags: android, reflection

My question is simple:

If I want to access a field in the internal classes, through java reflection, do I need to have my device rooted to make a field accessible with `.setAccessible(true)`?

Comment: No, rooting doesn't have anything to do with visibility of class members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `323go` said, rooting your phone has nothing to do with the visibility of class members.

You need proper visibility control, that's all :)